# How do I keep a DependencyProperty of List<string> in sync when elements are added?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm making an application in WPF and wanted to bind a `List<string>` to an `ItemsControl` using a `DataTemplate`. However, when I try to `Add` elements to the list, the changes aren't reflected in my interface.

I've tried searching for answers relating to collections and dependency properties, but no one seems to even acknowledge that this is a problem. The documentation on Microsoft's websites don't provide any help either.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PathsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Paths",
        typeof(List<string>),
        typeof(MainWindow),
        new PropertyMetadata(new List<string>())
    );

    public IList<string> Paths {
        get { return GetValue(PhotoPathsProperty) as IList<string>; }
        set { SetValue(PhotoPathsProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainWindow() {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

        WatermarkPath = "filepath";
        PhotoPaths = new List<string>();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog {
            Filter = ".PNG|*.png|.JPG|*.jpg",
            Title = "Open Photo Image(s)"
        };
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true) {
                foreach (var path in dialog.FileNames) {
                PhotoPaths.Add(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="PE_WaterMarker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PE_WaterMarker"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Header="Watermark" Margin="0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=WatermarkPath}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button x:Name="button" Grid.Column="1" Content="Browse" Click="Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Header="Images">
            <StackPanel>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Paths}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Browse"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Remove"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
                <Button Content="Add Image(s)" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: You need to use a `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of a basic list.

Comment: It is worth noting: WPF was designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. And what you are doing does not look like a (full) MVVM pattern. I did write a intro into MVVM a while back and it should still be good to get you started: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: It's worth looking at [Rx](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html) as well.